# How to get events when the system is suspended and then resuming

Tags: c#, .net, power-management

i wanna know the current system state whether its suspend or resume. i already tried    `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;`

```
private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  log.DebugFormat("System Power event {0}", e.Mode.ToString());
}
```

i wanna fetch the status of a system on frequent interval. i dont wanna use WMI query also. is there any other way to detect the system state.

Comment: Programs don't run in suspend, and I'm not sure what "resume" is.

Comment: @RonBeyer Then you can ask what he means. As you can see, it's a perfectly valid question. The event is triggered before suspending the computer and the resume event is triggered once the computer has been awaken again.

Comment: If you want to track how long the computer is suspended/active just save the date/time of the last triggered event and diff the new event date with it.

Answer (score 0):

Then, you can use SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged event to know whether the system is getting suspended (When you hibernate or sleep the suspend will happen).

```
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(OnPowerModeChanged);


    private static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Mode)
        {
            case PowerModes.Resume:
                MessageBox.Show("PowerMode: OS is resuming from suspended state");
                break;

            case PowerModes.Suspend:
                MessageBox.Show("PowerMode: OS is about to be suspended");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.